# videojs requesting fullscreen on first time play

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video.js

I am using videojs for my video player. My app is locked in portrait, but when I play the video for the first time (when the big play button is visible), I want to enter fullscreen. if a user exits the fullscreen, the app should be brought back to portrait mode and playing the video inline, not fullscreen. If a user wants to go back to fullscreen mode, he has to enter it by tapping on the fullscreen toggle at the bottom right of the player.
I made it work with entering the fullscreen mode by calling

```
this.player.bigPlayButton.on('tap', () => {
  if (fullscreenOnStart) {
    this.player.requestFullscreen();
  }
});
```

However, when I tap outside the big play button (which is centered), it won't enter the tap event of the bigPlayButton and the video will not be played in fullscreen. Do you guys know which tap event I have to listen to, to request fullscreen mode? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try PlayToggle ?

Comment: @Dave but that's the play button you are talking about. When the BigPlayButton is shown, there is no control element seen except a big play button in the middle of the video. When I click anywhere on the video but not on the big play button itself, it will still start the video, but it won't react on the tap event handler of the big play button.

Answer (score 0):

I added an event listener to the div element to achieve what I want. Now it's still only happening when the big play button is visible, but I can click outside the button too.

```
this.player.el().addEventListener('touchend', () => {
  if (!this.player.hasStarted() && fullscreenOnStart) {
    this.player.requestFullscreen();
  }
});
```

If anyone knows a better way to achieve this or if videojs has something for that, I'm still interested to know.

Comment: I have used videojs 'play' event to check the currentTime. If the video is played and the current time is undefined or less than 1 second then request a full screen. It works okay for us.